# Getting a cookie from a image http request with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, jquery-mobile, cookies

i'm working on with mobile xdk from intel (to create mobile hybrid app) and theres something new that is being difficult.

I've to get a image (a captcha, but the image is .php) from a domain, the thing is the image is generated automatically, and it utilizes the PHPSSID from cookie to compare the captcha with the text sent by post to login.

So i need to get the cookie from http request that got the image, so i could send it again with the login form to make remote login work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's part of the session variables, just call `session_start` again.

Comment: The thing inst in PHP, i need to get on the HTML inside the app on XDK. works like this XDK opens a http connection to remote site then get a image(captcha) from there..i need when getting the image also get the cookie used in the http request, to store to send when the login event fires..